# D8: Multilingual configuration and dynamic content

Tags: i18n-l10n, importing-exporting, configuration

I'm currently working on a multilingual Drupal 8 project that also takes advantage of D8's new CMI system *(Buzzwords: Content Manangement Initiative)*. Is there some sort of best practice here?

I would like editors to be free to translate different languages without reverting back to what is said in .yml files when doing an import.
It is possible to run `drush cim --partial` and simply skip "deleted" files which would be the case if you were to gitignore the `config/sync/language` directory but I'm not too keen about this idea since it would have an effect on so much more (all deleted config files in the future would be skipped).